# Is there a spell used to enchant a place to protect it from Squibs?

Tags: harry-potter, spells, squib

Spells for hiding or making a place invisible, or a barrier for muggles, are only for muggles and do not intend to include a Squib, who is considered as a person who was born from a family honored with magical blood, but does not obtain the wizarding sorcery.

However, is there a spell regarding of how can you enchant a place from Squibs? For example, Hogwarts. Dumbledore enchanted the place, which when a Muggle sees the area, the Muggle will not see the castle, but just an old ruined sign, as it was described in the books. But what if a headmaster also want to protect the place from Squibs?

For a while, let's disregard Filch with this situation.

Comment: What does disregarding Filch have to do with this?

Comment: @CHEESE he's a squib working at Hogwarts

Comment: We don't know that muggle repelling charms exclude squibs. Certainly, we've seen squibs operate inside such charms but we've seen muggles do the same - see Hermione's parents in Diagon Alley.

Comment: @Glimmervoid I think it excludes squibs. I mean, performing the enchantments were only intended to protect them from muggles, which Hermione said in book 7. Yes, I forgot about that part. Does Diagon Alley also has its Muggle Enchantments?

Comment: @Glimmervoid - We've seen two squibs operate inside Hogwarts, despite it being hidden from Muggles.

Comment: @ibid Exactly my point. We know that muggles can operate inside protected areas, assuming they are lead inside - see Hermione's parents in Diagon Alley. Likewise, the fact that squibs are able to operate inside Hogwarts is not evidence that they could pass through such charms un-aided. Granted, it is not evidence of the opposite either.

Comment: @Glimmervoid, does Diagon Alley has Muggle defense enchantments?

Comment: @BookStriker, There seems to be. "Dumbledore handed Riddle the envelope containing his list of equipment, and, after telling Riddle exactly how to get to the Leaky Cauldron from the orphanage, he said, ‘You will be able to see it, although Muggles around you – non-magical people, that is – will not. Ask for Tom the barman – easy enough to remember, as he shares your name –’ Half-Blood Prince. I suppose we could speculate the ant-muggle protections don't extend to the street proper but Pottermore also says "A busy shopping street completely unseen by Muggles..."

Comment: What's the point? Squibs are pureblood and live in the Wizarding World

Answer (score 1):

### No. There's no need for one.

The [International Statute of Secrecy](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/thing/international-statute-of-secrecy/) only applies to Muggles, not Squibs. What Squibs lack is the ability to perform magic. They are not barred from knowing of or living in the magical world. The Muggle-repelling spells that surround Hogwarts and the Quidditch World Cup stadium are there to enforce the International Statute of Secrecy and to prevent Muggles from finding out about the wizarding world by chancing across a magical location. These spells are not applicable to Squibs since they are able to come and go in those locations the same as an ordinary wizard or witch.

The specific spell which relates to Hogwarts only applies to Muggles. There's no evidence that it would have any effect on a Squib.

> “It’s bewitched,” said Hermione. “If a **Muggle** looks at it, all they see is a moldering old ruin with a sign over the entrance saying DANGER, DO NOT ENTER, UNSAFE.”
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 11, Aboard the Hogwarts Express)*.</sub>

Filch is a good example a Squib co-existing amongst wizards and witches. But we can tell from the examples of other Squibs that there was nothing in place to stop them travelling to magical locations like Hogwarts. Mrs Figg chose to live in a Muggle community but was able to travel into the Ministry of Magic to give evidence in support of Harry. The only other Squib I'm aware of, [Angus Buchanan](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/scottish-rugby) also lived as a Muggle. However, he published a book (*My Life as a Squib*) for the magical community, which presumably would've involved travelling to a magical location (Diagon Alley, for example) to secure a publishing deal. All in all, we have no example of a Squib being barred from a magical location.

Comment: So your answer is "not that we know of"?

Comment: @ibid And that it's unnecessary as Squibs aren't covered by the ISS.

Comment: But how is that relevant to the question? OP already knows that standard Muggle-repelling charms don't work on squibs. That's why they're asking if there's a different spell.

Comment: @ibid Yes but it's also important to cover the reason for the Muggle-repelling spells. Not only do we not know of any Squib-repellenting ones but there is no need for them.

Comment: "*But what if a headmaster also want to protect the place from Squibs?*" Sounds like a good enough reason.

Comment: @ibid Well, in the case of Hogwarts, the Squib simply wouldn't get a Hogwarts letter. There's no need to put up spells against them since they were never invited. Even if a Squib like Buchanan managed to gate-crash they won't get past the Sorting Hat. Again, there's no security risk. So no reason to create anti-Squib magic. I don't think we can be more definitive than 'no cause, no evidence' with this kind of what-if scenario.

Comment: Argus Filch the caretaker was at Hogwarts and he is a Squib.